# Wordpress theme generate error for mysql SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Wordpress** theme generate following error for mysql:

```
####
+---------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id      | User             | Host      | db               |Command| Time   | State      | Info                                                                                               | Progress |
+---------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 9013075 | nilamigh_nilami2 | localhost | nilamigh_nilami2 | Query | 116398 | statistics | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpli_sbafat18posts.ID FROM wpli_sbafat18posts LEFT JOIN wpli_sbafat18te | 0.000 |
| 9014193 | nilamigh_nilami2 | localhost | nilamigh_nilami2 | Query | 116097 | statistics | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpli_sbafat18posts.ID FROM wpli_sbafat18posts LEFT JOIN wpli_sbafat18te | 0.000 |

####
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting by indenting each line of SQL code with four spaces.

Comment: You're not LEFT JOINing *ON* anything

Comment: @FreedomPride Thanks for formatting

Comment: @Strawberry Kindly explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by disabling "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" query that solution found in this post
["WordPress: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, why it’s slow and what to do about it"](https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-database-queries-speed-sql_calc_found_rows)